# How to convert Speech to text in c#? (without using any sdk or System.speech.*)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I know that this is not the first thread on this topic,but I have searched all the posts regarding this and not found what I am looking for. I'm doing my graduation project and speech recognition is part of it. I have searched a lot regarding it and found out about the different SDK that are available and even the Speech recognizer engine in c#. I cant include these codes, I have to try it on my one from scratch.

Right now I have been able to take voice input from microphone and store it into a wave file.
I want to pass the same file or the byte stream to the speech recognition that will convert the voice to text

I would would be really thankful if someone have already done this and can give me a link for a paper or a code I can take guidance from.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Search for fast Fourier transform (FFT) and hidden-markov-models and also a good book and much time.

Comment: If you are not going to use any SDK, then maybe you should research speech recognition algorithms first, and then later ask the specific questions related to its implementation in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use any SDK or the `System.speech` integrated namespace, you have to develop your speech recognition library by your own ...

Maybe you can take a look to some open source speech recognition library to get an idea ... Take a look at [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) for example .